# Tree-shaking with rollup

Tags: javascript, rollup, tree-shaking

I have a project in which I bundle a components library using Rollup (generating a bundle.esm.js file). These components are then used in another project, that generates web pages which use these components - each page is using different components.
The problem is, that the entire components library is always bundled with the different page bundles, regardless of which components I'm using, unnecessarily increasing the bundle size.

This is my Rollup setup:

```
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import pkg from './package.json';

const extensions = [
  '.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx',
];
export default [
  {
    input: './src/base/index.ts',
    plugins: [
      peerDepsExternal(),
      resolve({ extensions }),
      babel({
        exclude: 'node_modules/**',
        extensions,
      }),
      commonjs(),
    ],
    output: [
      { file: pkg.main, format: 'cjs', sourcemap: true },
      { file: pkg.module, format: 'es', sourcemap: true },
    ],
    watch: {
      clearScreen: false,
    },
  },
];
```

I have "modules" set to false in webpack, as well.

Answer (score 11):

As you don't know which components of your Component Library (CL) will be needed by the adopters repositories you need to export everything but in a way
the adopters can execute a tree-shaking on your CL when they do their own build (and just include what they really need).

In a few words, you have to make your CL, tree-shakable. In order to achieve this, on your CL repo you have to:

- Use bundlers that support tree-shaking (rollup, webpack, etc..)
- Create the build for modules of type es/esm, NOT commonJS/cjs, etc..
- Ensure **no** transpilers/compilers (babel,tsconfig, etc..) usually used as plugins, transform your ES module syntax to another module syntax.
  By the default, the behavior of the popular Babel preset *@babel/preset-env* may break this rule, see the [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#modules) for more details.

// *babelrc.json* example that worked for me

```
[
  "@babel/preset-env",
  {
    "targets": ">0.2%, not dead, not op_mini all"
  }
],
```

- In the codebase, you always have to use `import/export` (no `require`) syntax, and import specifically the things you need only.

  `import arrayUtils from "array-utils";` //WRONG

  `import { unique, implode, explode } from "array-utils";` //OK
- Configure your *sideEffects* on the package.json.

  `"sideEffects": ["**/*.css"],`  //example 1

  `"sideEffects": false,`  //example 2
- DO NOT create a single-bundle file but keep the files separated after your build process (official docs don't say this but was the only solution that worked for me)

// *rollup.config.js* example

```
const config = [
    {
        input: 'src/index.ts',
        output: [
            {
                format: 'esm', // set ES modules
                dir: 'lib', // indicate not create a single-file
                preserveModules: true, // indicate not create a single-file
                preserveModulesRoot: 'src', // optional but useful to create a more plain folder structure
                sourcemap: true, //optional
            },
        ],
        ... }]
```

- Additionally, you may need to change your module entry point in order the adopters can directly access to the proper *index.js* file where you are exporting everthing:

// *package.json* example

```
   {
    ...
    "module": "lib/index.js", //set the entrypoint file
   }
```

Note: Remember that tree-shaking is executed by an adopter repository that has a build process that supports tree-shaking (eg: a CRA repo) and usually tree-shaking is just executed on **prod** mode (`npm run build`), no on **dev** mode. So be sure to properly test if this is working or not.

Comment: This answer deserves to be accepted. Good job, Juanma.

Answer (score 9):

There are things you will need to do to achieve treeshakable code from both sides - the built package and the project using it.

From your code snippet, I see that you have not add flag `preserveModules: true` in the rollup config file to prevent the build output from bundling. Webpack can not treeshake a bundled file [FYI](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/9337#issuecomment-507074474).

```js
export default {
  ...
  preserveModules: true,
  ...
}
```

On the side of the project that using it, you have to specify `sideEffects` in the `package.json` - read the [doc](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) to know how to config them. Beside that, the `optimization` in webpack has to has `sideEffects: true`, also read the doc [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationsideeffects).

Hope this helps!